# is this grammar ambiguous

Tags: context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar

I want to convert this grammar to an unambiguous grammar:

```
S -> if E then S
   | if E then S else S
   | a
E -> b
```

I found a solution which is more complicated than my solution but I'm not sure if my solution is correct:

```
S -> if E then T else S
   | if E then S 
   | a
T -> if E then T else T 
   | a
E -> b
```

So is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK to me. It's really not much different from the standard solution:

```
stmt      : matched | unmatched
matched   : "if" expr "then" matched "else" matched
          | other_stmt
unmatched : "if" expr "then" unmatched
          | "if" expr "then" matched "else" unmatched
```

The  advantage of the standard solution is that `other_stmt` (`a` in your grammar) is not duplicated, and the grammar is easier to extend with other compound statements. For example, if we add the `while` statement:

```
stmt      : matched | unmatched
matched   : "if" expr "then" matched "else" matched
          | "while" matched
          | other_stmt
unmatched : "if" expr "then" unmatched
          | "if" expr "then" matched "else" unmatched
          | "while" unmatched
```